# Improving reading skills

Tags: vocabulary, reading, memorization

I am big fan of Sherlock Holmes and I watched all Tv series and movies. Also I want to read all Sherlock Holmes stories in English. I need to improve my reading skills and expand my vocabulary.

So I need an effective technique for memorize vocabulary.

Comment: If you mean that you need to learn the words before you encounter them in your reading, I think this is actually the wrong approach. Just pick it up and read it. That is how you will learn. Let your curiosity guide you; if you feel like looking stuff up as you encounter it, make that as easy to do on a whim as possible.

Comment: I'd like to mention that memorizing vocabulary isn't actually that broad of a question. It can easily be answered in a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: There is no such effective technique. You need to learn the words when you read. Memorising is not a permanent learning. You will see an unknown word one day in the book, you will look it up; and the next day or the other day when you see it again, you will realise you already learnt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Read more and often. The more times you encounter a word, the more chances you'll have to remember it.
- Look up words you don't know every time.
- Start with books for a younger audience if you haven't already. Depending on your level of English already, this could be anything from children's books to books for teenagers, like the Hunger Games (which I recommend.)
- If a book or text is too hard for you, try something a little easier. There's no point looking up every fourth word and not remembering any of them.
- If you're struggling to remember a specific word, repeat it aloud along with it's definition, draw a picture to associate it with, or whatever else helps you to normally remember things. This might include setting definition tests, where you write a list of words and then their definitions.
- **Most importantly:** don't try to learn the entire English language before reading whatever material you want to. Read other texts before, and use those to learn.